# Azure DevOps/Pipeline IP is changing randomly so I can not use Azure SQL Database because of firewall rules

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Azure DevOps/Pipeline IP is changing randomly so I can not use Azure SQL Database because of firewall rules.

What is the solution in this case?

Answer (score 7):

You can create a firewall rule based on the current ip of the agent before connecting with the database like so:

```
  - task: AzureCLI@2
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: [name of service connection]
      scriptType: pscore
      scriptLocation: inlineScript
      inlineScript: |
        # Set firewall on server open for the agent
        $agentIp = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("http://checkip.dyndns.com") -replace "[^\d\.]"
        az sql server firewall-rule create -g $(rg) -s $(server) -n test --start-ip-address $agentIp --end-ip-address $agentIp
```

In a similar way you can remove it at the end of the pipeline.

Comment: Do you know a solution using a template instead of command? You are showing the correct way but I need the same thing using a template.

Comment: Is this change what you meant?

Comment: I am talking about the template we select from the task list.

Comment: Are you referring to the classic pipeline maybe? My answer applies to the yaml pipelines.

Comment: I know you had given a solution for YAML. I wanted to get a solution using a task.

Comment: In the classic pipelines the task exists under the name "Azure CLI". The parameters are the same as in the YAML task described here.

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet  Are you using `Azure SQL Database Deployment` task in your pipeline?

Comment: @Levi Lu-MSFT yes

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet You can set the `IpDetectionMethod(Specify Firewall Rules Using)` field to `AutoDetect` for Azure SQL Database Deployment task, which will automatically add the agent ip to the firewall rule.

Comment: In our case, we are using classic Release pipeline for PROD deployment, and we have set the Auto Detect for IPs in firewall rules as Azure Agent will take dynamic allotted IPs. And at the end we have set to delete the firewall rules after task completion. But as it's a PROD deployment, we have set delete lock at RG level, so our Release task deployment is failing as it's not able to delete the firewall rule created for Agent. How we can tackle this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

I have added Azure IP range in Azure SQL Database firewall then it works.
For example:

```
Start IP 13.107.6.0 and End IP 13.107.6.255
```

and

```
Start IP 13.107.43.0 and End IP 13.107.43.255
```

I am not sure this is a permanent solution.

Microsoft Doc Reference [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops)