# Error when deploying DACPAC via Azure DevOps Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, dac

I am flushing out a CI/CD process with Azure SQL DB deployed via Azure DevOps Pipelines.  I am using the Adventure works database and set up a visual studio project importing the schema.

I have a pipeline configured to publish the dacpac and run a subsequent deployment using the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 and am getting the below error:

```
2020-10-10T02:36:34.1421137Z ##[error]Unable to connect to target server 'server.database.windows.net'. Please verify the connection information such as the server name, login credentials, and firewall rules for the target server.
2020-10-10T02:36:34.1605855Z ##[error]Windows logins are not supported in this version of SQL Server.
2020-10-10T02:36:34.2143924Z ##[error]The Azure SQL DACPAC task failed. SqlPackage.exe exited with code 1.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
2020-10-10T02:36:34.2522414Z ##[section]Finishing: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment
```

I am using windows latest and here is my YAML pipeline:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'


jobs: 
- job: BuildDeploySQL
  variables:
  - group: SQLServerLogin
  steps:
  - task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '**\*.sln'
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
  - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'Subscription Name here'
      AuthenticationType: 'server'
      ServerName: 'server.database.windows.net'
      DatabaseName: 'AdventureWorks'
      SqlUsername: 'sqladmin'
      SqlPassword: ${{ variables.Password }}
      deployType: 'DacpacTask'
      DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
      DacpacFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\s\AdventureWorks\bin\Debug\*.dacpac'
      IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

I have tried to deploy from my local machine and it is successful using the same sql credentials.  Additionally I have confirmed that the SQL Database has allow Azure Services enabled.  I have also tried to deploy the dacpac to a new empty database and get this same error.

I do believe this could be just a generic error message as my deployment logs do show a successful connection to the server:

```
2020-10-10T02:36:18.7912964Z Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "server.database.windows.net" -Database "AdventureWorks" -Username "sqladmin"  -Password ******  -Inputfile 
....
2020-10-10T02:36:33.0554895Z Initializing deployment (Start)
```

** Update
Just to rule out I did create a new SQL Login with DBO_owner permissions and ran the deployment using that and got the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue was the password secret contained characters which escaped Powershell.  Wrapping the secret in "" resolved it.

Comment: Can you elaborate ? Paste the actual parameter that's in your pipeline now? Where are the quotes exactly ? I get syntax error

Comment: In my case it was the same issue, I was not using yaml, but my password was also containing ". Even though it was escaped automatically for me (can see it by enabling System.Debug), I still had an issue. I was using AD password authentication method and after I changed the pw to eliminate " it started working as expected

Answer (score 3):

Above error is probably because the build agent ip is not allow-listed in the firewall rules of your Azure SQL Database. See the this link about [IP ranges for Microsoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#to-identify-the-possible-ip-ranges-for-microsoft-hosted-agents).

You can check the firewall rules setting of your azure database, and try allowing all IP ranges.

You can aslo add Azure CLi task to get the agent ip and set a firewall rule for your azure database to allow the agent ip dynamically in your pipeline. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64282741/azure-devops-pipeline-ip-is-changing-randomly-so-i-can-not-use-azure-sql-databas).

```
steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'azureSubscription'
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
     
     $agentIp = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("http://checkip.dyndns.com") -replace "[^\d\.]"
     
     az sql server firewall-rule create -g $(rg) -s $(server) -n test --start-ip-address $agentIp --end-ip-address $agentIp
```

You can also create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) on your local machine/Azure VM. and run your pipeline on this self-hosted agent. Note to allow-list your local machine ip for the azure database.

Comment: This is great information!  I did add the above task to my ADO pipeline.  The task did work and updated the firewall settings; however, I am still getting the same error message as stated above.  The tasks are not being ran in parallel so the deployment step should be on the same agent.

Comment: @DreadedFrost  Have you tried using connection string as Authentication Type?

Comment: Issue was a special character in the secreate password.  Wrapping it in quotes resolved it.

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT Doesn't `IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'` have the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task create the firewall rule?